# Template metaprogramming within the body of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a partially specialised template function within the body of a template class/struct. The partial specialisation is done to perform recursive template metaprogramming.

```
template<size_t N>
struct my_class {

template<size_t D> double my_func(...){}

template<> double my_func<0>(...){}

double other_func(...){ return my_func<N-1>(...); }
};
```

but g++ (using the *-std=c++0x* option) complains saying can't partially specialize template function within a class/struct and forces me to write the template functions *my_func* outside of the class scope in a separate *namespace*, as if they were static, eventually passing all the *private* class variables and making the code very messy (all the member variables which would be easily referenced by *this*).

Is there a way a can do partial template specialization (I could make the functions as static members of private sub classes of *my_class* too) and metaprogramming within the same class?

This makes the code cleaner and a lot easier to maintain.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc 4.6.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by overloading the function (not specializing it) then using `enable_if` to selectively only enable one or other of the overloads:

```
template<size_t D> typename std::enable_if<D!=0, double>::type my_func(...){}

template<size_t D> typename std::enable_if<D==0, double>::type my_func(...){}
```

The `enable_if` constraint means that when `D!=0` only the first overload is a viable function, and when `D==0` only the second overload is a viable function.

In C++03 you can do the same thing with `boost::enable_if_c`.

My preferred solution would replace the ugly `enable_if` usage with a custom trait type, maybe something like this:

```
template<size_t> struct if_zero { typedef double disable; };
template<> struct if_zero<0> { typedef double enable; };

template<size_t D> typename if_zero<D>::disable my_func(...){}
template<size_t D> typename if_zero<D>::enable  my_func(...){}
```

This has the same effect, but in a more [literate programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) style.

Another form that's even easier to read would be:

```
template<bool, typename T> struct If_ { typedef T enable; };
template<typename T> struct If_<false, T> { };

template<bool B, typename T> using If = typename If_<B, T>::enable;

template<size_t D> If<D!=0, double> my_func(...){}
template<size_t D> If<D==0, double> my_func(...){}
```

I think the ["Concepts Lite"](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/new-paper-n3580-concepts-lite-andrew-sutton-bjarne-stroustrup-gabriel-dos-r) proposal would allow this in a far cleaner way by constraining the second overload like so:

```
template<size_t D> double my_func(...){}

template<size_t D> requires (D == 0)
  double my_func(...){}
```

Here the second overload can only be called when `D==0` and will be chosen by overload resolution because it is more constrained than the first overload.

Comment: SFINAE for the win eh? :-) I was genuinely hoping the new standard to support partial specified template metaprogramming out of the box, without these ugly syntactic tricks...

Comment: See the `If` alias template version I added, which I think is about the best syntax you can get in C++11.  If concepts make it into C++17 you'll be able to use constraints.